# Group variable based on list with strings - Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement, any

My python code doesn't return what I expect it to do and I hope you can help me.

I have a dataset that consists of a long list of venues in a city and a column with the venue category type (e.g. 'italian restaurant'). Now I'd like to make an additional column to my dataframe with the broader category group ('eating') based on a list with strings to search on.

I hoped to see the following outputs in my dataframe with these four example venue categories:

- 'italian restaurant' → 'eating'
- 'bed & breakfast' → 'sleeping'
- 'museum of modern art' → 'sightseeing'
- 'gym' → 'other'

I tried to solve it with the following:

```
sleeping = ['bed','hostel','hotel']

eating = ['bar','bistro','cafe','pub','restaurant']

sightseeing = ['museum','theater','zoo']

def catgroup(cat):
    for cat in df['venue_cat']:
        if any(s in cat for s in sleeping):
            return 'sleeping'
        elif any(s in cat for s in eating):
            return 'eating'
        elif any(s in cat for s in sightseeing):
            return 'sightseeing'
        else:
            return 'other'
```

Followed by

```
df['cat_group'] = df['venue_cat'].apply(catgroup)
```

Unfortunately, **all venues return the same category from the first elif statement: eating**.
I know it's the first elif statement because if I change the order of the elifs (eating vs sightseeing) I only get: **sightseeing**

Would love to hear your solutions to this issue, because I just don't see it

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the `cat` parameter of the function correctly.  I would expect that apply is called multiple times (once per row) so the `cat` parameter already contains the value you want to check (or a single element array with that value).  By using a for on the df, you are actually basing the result on the first row of the whole dataframe and responding with the same value for all calls to your function.

Within the function, your code is similar to a switch statement (which Python doesn't have but can easily be simulated).

To simulate a plain vanilla switch statement I usually define a helper function like this:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c:v in c
```

Which is used in a one pass for-in statement:

```
x = 3
for case in switch(x):
    if case(1):   return "one"
    if case(2,4): return "even"
    if case(3):   return "three"
```

In this case the comparison condition is a little different and would benefit from using a regular expression instead of 's in cat'.  So lets define a wordSwitch() helper function that looks for whole word patterns:

```
import re

def wordSwitch(v): yield lambda *c: any(re.search(r'\b('+w+')\b',v) for w in c)
```

Your code could then look like this:

```
def catGroup(cat):
    for case in wordSwitch(cat):                 # could need to be cat[0]
        if case(*sleeping):    return "sleeping"
        if case(*eating):      return "eating"
        if case(*sightseeing): return "sightseeing"
    return "other"
```

*Note that, although i'm not familiar with `.apply()`, I believe it receives the field (or row) value directly so you don't need to (and probably must not) get data from df['..'].  You should try printing the value of `cat` that the function receives to be sure.*

You could also place the word lists directly in the case() parts:

```
for case in wordSwitch(cat):
    if case('bed','hostel','hotel'):                   return "sleeping"
    if case('bar','bistro','cafe','pub','restaurant'): return "eating"
    if case('museum','theater','zoo'):                 return "sightseeing"
return "other"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation on what's wrong with my code. I came to realize the for loop in my function is incorrect. After adjusting it, the code works. Will share the solution here.
Also tried your solution but didn't get it to work now. 'p' is not defined and I don't know what your abbreviations stand for.

Comment: `p.search` --> `re.search` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for loop in the function, so that:

```
def catgroup(cat):
    if any(s in cat for s in sleeping):
        return 'sleeping'
    elif any(s in cat for s in shopping):
        return 'shopping'
    elif any(s in cat for s in eating):
        return 'eating'
    elif any(s in cat for s in sightseeing):
        return 'sightseeing'
    else:
        return 'other'

df['cat_group'] = df['venue_cat'].apply(catgroup)
```